# PEP8: continuation line over-indented for visual indent

Tags: python

I have this line of code which goes over the line and when testing for pep8 errors I get:
line too long. So to try and fix this I used slash('\') but then I get continuation line over-indented for visual indent. What can I do to fix this?

[image]

Things I've tried:

```
if first_index < 0 or second_index > \
   self._number_of_plates - 1:
    raise ValueError

continuation line over-indented for visual indent

if first_index < 0 \ 
   or second_index > \
   self._number_of_plates - 1:
    raise ValueError

continuation line over-indented for visual indent

if first_index < 0 or \
   second_index > self._number_of_plates - 1:
    raise ValueError

continuation line over-indented for visual indent

if first_index \
   < 0 or second_index \
   > self._number_of_plates - 1:
     raise ValueError

continuation line over-indented for visual indent
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The line-extending backslash has the issue of having trailing whitespace that can break your code. This is a popular fix and is PEP8-compliant:

```
if (first_index < 0 or
    second_index > self._number_of_plates - 1):
```

Comment: Thanks David however now I get 'continuation line does not distinguish itself from next logical line' with that line of code. edit: fixed!

Comment: For future readers - this means that the next line has the same indent, so in that case the second in the code above can be shifted for 1 more tab to the right.

Comment: Indenting the second line would severely impact readability IMHO.  My technique here is to remove the parentheses and mark the line continuation with a backslash.  The only problem I've found is that it doesn't fix anything when trying to use multiple "open()" contextmanagers in a single "with".  Adding parentheses results in a complete syntax error, making me somewhat curious as to how this is parsed differently from a standard tuple.

Answer (score 1):

A continuation line is indented farther than it should be for a visual indent.

Anti-pattern
In this example, the string "World" is indented two spaces farther than it should be.

```
print("Python", ("Hello",
                   "World"))
```

Best practice

```
print("Python", ("Hello",
                 "World"))
```

reference: https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/E127.html

Comment: The `print()` example from Flake8 rules is childishly trivial. A concrete code example from real world would be more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the popular [`black`](https://github.com/psf/black) formatter does:

```
if (
    first_index < 0
    or second_index > self._number_of_plates - 1
):
    raise ValueError
```

This looks fine to me. However, it is probably a good idea to refactor so that the code isn't 7 levels of indentation deep in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

For lines that are too long (e.g. > 79 characters), you can use parentheses to group your conditions:

```
if (first_index < 0 
        or second_index > self._number_of_plates - 1
        or condition2
        and candition3):
    raise ValueError
```

Note that any boolean conditions (`or`, `and`) should go at the start of the line before the condition.

In your case, there is a special rule because of the `if (...)` construct:

> When the conditional part of an if-statement is long enough to require
> that it be written across multiple lines, it's worth noting that the
> combination of a two character keyword (i.e. if), plus a single space,
> plus an opening parenthesis creates a natural 4-space indent for the
> subsequent lines of the multiline conditional. This can produce a
> visual conflict with the indented suite of code nested inside the
> if-statement, which would also naturally be indented to 4 spaces. This
> PEP takes no explicit position on how (or whether) to further visually
> distinguish such conditional lines from the nested suite inside the
> if-statement. Acceptable options in this situation include, but are
> not limited to:

```
# No extra indentation.
if (this_is_one_thing and
    that_is_another_thing):
    do_something()

# Add a comment, which will provide some distinction in editors
# supporting syntax highlighting.
if (this_is_one_thing and
    that_is_another_thing):
    # Since both conditions are true, we can frobnicate.
    do_something()

# Add some extra indentation on the conditional continuation line.
if (this_is_one_thing
        and that_is_another_thing):
    do_something()
```

> (Also see the discussion of whether to break before or after binary
> operators below.)

Source: [PEP 8 Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id15)